# Continuity of a function when homomorphism is given.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$, for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$ and $f$ is continuous at $x = 0$ then prove that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$.

We know that $\mathbb R$ is field and every non zero element of $\mathbb R$ has multiplicative inverse. But I'm unable to connect continuity with homomorphism. So please help me

Comment: Hint: $f(x+h)-f(x)=f(x)+f(h)-f(x)=f(h)$

Answer (score 1):

Continuity of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is obtained iff $\lim_{h\to 0} f(x+h)-f(x)=0$. As I noted in my comment, this expression is equal to $\lim_{h\to 0} f(x)+f(h)-f(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}f(h)$. By assumption, we know that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ thus proving: $\lim_{h\to 0} f(h)=0$

Comment: Thank sir, you are great.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} f(x + a)  
= \lim_{x\to 0} (f(x) + f(a))  
= \lim_{x\to 0} f(x) + \lim_{x\to 0} f(a)   
= f(0) + f(a) = f(0 + a) = f(a)$

Comment: This is also a nice answer of my question. Thanks a lot.